# Image Upload to a server with user details

Tags: android

I'm trying to upload user information to a server. I can upload the image. But at that time I can't attach user details with that. I'm using the below code for uploading image. so How can I add user details to server?

```
try
    {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs & Outputs
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Enable POST method
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Read file
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

    System.out.println(serverResponseCode);
    System.out.println(serverResponseMessage);
    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    //Exception handling
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

put your information in bundle and append these information with url:

```
public String makeUrl(String url, Bundle params, Context context) {
url = yourBaseURL + url + "?" + encodeUrl(params);
Log.d("my url is", " URL: " + url);
return url;
}
```

and encode url method is

```
public String encodeUrl(Bundle parameters) {

try {
if (parameters == null) {
return "";
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean first = true;
for (String key : parameters.keySet()) {
if (first)
first = false;
else
sb.append("&");
Log.d(key + " = ", "" + parameters.getString(key));
sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(key) + "="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(parameters.getString(key)));
}

return sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return "";
}
```

Comment: I have to pass parameters like username,password, profile pic......Can I add username, password and image as bytearray to the bundle?...If yes...How can I do?

Comment: me also facing the same problem.

Comment: you can append userName,password with url.and upload your image using post method.